# Looking for a method to iterate through ImageViews in an activity with kotlin

Tags: android, loops, kotlin, imageview

I have an activity with 12 Image views in a 3x4 matrix. I want to replace the image and other properties of each ImageView with different resources programmatically. I can't seem to find any way to iterate through the views with a loop so am having to hard code each change. I managed to get the ImageViews into an array which helps but I am hoping there is a better way. I looked at KotlinX.Synthetic and data/view binding but they don't seem to help.
E.g to create the ImageView array I have had to do this:

```
 var imgArray = arrayOf(findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.img01))
 imgArray += findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.img02)
 imgArray += findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.img03)
 imgArray += findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.img04)
 imgArray += findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.img05)
 imgArray += findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.img06)
 imgArray += findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.img07)
 imgArray += findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.img08)
 imgArray += findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.img09)
 imgArray += findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.img10)
 imgArray += findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.img11)
 imgArray += findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.img12)
```

I was hoping to do something like:

```
var i = 1
for (listView in listViews) {
    imgArray += findViewById<ImageView>("R.id.img" + i.tostring())
i++
}
```

But that oviously wont work.
Any help would be much appreciated. I have some experience with other languages but new to kotlin/java/android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually go with the first example in [Gabe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74128285/13598222), just listing the IDs and using that to create useful collections you can iterate over. But here are a couple of other options that might be more suitable depending on the situation:

***Find all views of a given type***

```
container.children.filterIsInstance<ImageView>()
```

This takes a reference to a `ViewGroup` (e.g. a `ConstraintLayout`, `GridLayout` etc.) and basically pulls out all the `View`s of a certain type. Useful if they're organised in some kind of container layout, not so much if everything's on the same level (like a `ConstraintLayout` encourages you to do) and there are other `View`s of the same type you don't want included.

Also, this only works on the direct descendants of the container, the stuff which has it as a parent. If any of that stuff has its own descendants, they aren't included (see the function below though!)

***Use tags***

*Tags* are a bit of data you can add to a `View`, in XML with the `tag` attribute, or in code with `setTag`. You could use this to identify which `ImageView`s you want, if organising them in the hierarchy isn't possible. (The hierarchy is better because there's no work and nothing to forget once it's set up - you just put your views in with the other views.)

There's a `findViewWithTag` function, but it only returns one `View`, which is no good when you have a group you want to grab. So we can write a helper function to grab *all* descendants of a `ViewGroup` (not just its immediate children):

```
fun ViewGroup.getAllDescendants(): Sequence<View> =
        children + children.filterIsInstance<ViewGroup>().flatMap { it.getAllDescendants() }
```

(This is useful because it can handle `View`s in a nested hierarchy, so it can help with the `filterByInstance` approach above too, if you have a container that everything you need is *inside*, but as part of an internal hierarchy.)

And now you can use that to get every `View` in the hierarchy, and filter on the tag you want

```
// start with the root view, e.g. 'view' or 'binding.root' - or any container
// you want to search inside
(view as ViewGroup).getAllDescendants()
        // you don't necessarily need to do this one, but it's safer and casts for you
        .filterIsInstance<ImageView>()
        .filter { it.tag == "cool image" }
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I usually go is

```
val imageViews = listOf(R.id.img1, R.id.img2, R.id.img3).map(findViewById(it))
```

that will build you a list of views in one line.

Or there is `resources.getIdentifier("nameOfDrawable", "drawable", this.getPackageName())` to get an id for a given name, if you really don't want to keep the list up to date and there is no variation in names.

Answer (score 0):

If the ImageViews are on the same parent layout you can just query the layout for its children.

You get a childrenlist.

Iterate the list.

You do not at forehand have to know how much image views there are.